# Google bot trying to access /mobile/ and /m/ links

Tags: google

Webmaster tools show in "URL Errors" links to m/ and mobile/.
My site have no active links to these URLs and they are not mentioned in sitemap. 
Why google trying to access them?

Comment: Does state where they were linked from in Webmaster Tools, by clicking the URL, then clicking 'Linked from' tab from pop up window.

Comment: There is no 'Linked from' tab just 'Error details' tab.